# React: object is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime-error

I have made component **TempCalculator** which will calculates whether the water would boil at a given temperature. Additionally, it renders the BoilingVerdict for the current input value.

```
const BoilingPeek = (props) => {
  return props.celsius >= 100 ? (
    <p>Water would boil.</p>
  ) : (
    <p>Water is would not boil.</p>
  );
};

class TempCalculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleTempChange = this.handleTempChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      temperature: "",
    };
  }

  handleTempChange(event) {
    this.setState({ temperature: event.target.name });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Temprature of water in celsius</legend>
        <input name={temperature} onChange={this.handleTempChange} />
        <BoilingPeek celsius={parseFloat(temperature)} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<TempCalculator/>,document.getElementById("root"))
```

**ERROR**
`'temperature' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: well it's right - you haven't defined `temperature` anywhere. Did you perhaps mean `this.state.temperature`? (I think you did, but you will soon discover other problems with your code...)

Answer (score 1):

that's because `temperature` is a state. use like this:

```
<input name={this.state.temperature} onChange={this.handleTempChange} />
<BoilingPeek celsius={parseFloat(this.state.temperature)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const BoilingPeek = (props) => {
  return props.celsius >= 100 ? (
    <p>Water would boil.</p>
  ) : (
    <p>Water is would not boil.</p>
  );
};

class TempCalculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleTempChange = this.handleTempChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      temperature: "",
    };
  }
  handleTempChange(e) {
    this.setState({ temperature: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Temprature of water in celsius</legend>
        <input
          value={this.state.temperature}
          onChange={this.handleTempChange}
        />
        <BoilingPeek celsius={parseFloat(this.state.temperature)} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<TempCalculator/>,document.getElementById("root"))
```

Thanks, it's solved